# How to add Multiple-Markers in google map

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need to add multiple marker in a google map (added google map by using googlemap library).I also added a marker in this map.
 for a single marker code :

Controller:

```
    $data['tunnels'] = $this->functional->getTunnelData();
    $config['center'] = '37.4419, -122.1419';
    $config['zoom'] = 'auto';
    $this->googlemaps->initialize($config);
    $marker = array();
    $marker['position'] = 'center';
    $this->googlemaps->add_marker($marker);
    $data['map'] = $this->googlemaps->create_map();
```

Model:

```
    $this->db->select('ult_tunnel.*,ult_country.name as country_name,ult_state.name as state_name,ult_city.name as city_name ')
                    ->join('ult_country','ult_country.id = ult_tunnel.country_id')
                    ->join('ult_state','ult_state.id = ult_tunnel.state_id')
                    ->join('ult_city','ult_city.id = ult_tunnel.city_id')
                    ->from('ult_tunnel')
                    ->where('ult_tunnel.status','Active')
                    ->get()->result();
```

View:

```
    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12" id="map">
        <?php echo $map['js']; ?>
        <?php echo $map['html']; ?>
    </div>
```

Please help me to adding multiple marker in this googlemap.
Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

**Edited:**

Table Structure:
It contains:

Id(int primary key)

name(varchar)

country(int)

state(int)

city(int)

status

i want to mark through name in google map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your code as following solution.

> Changes in your **Controller**:

```
$data['tunnels'] = $this->functional->getTunnelData();
$config['center'] = '37.4419, -122.1419';
$config['zoom'] = 'auto';
$this->googlemaps->initialize($config);

// First Marker
$marker = array();
$marker['position'] = '37.429, -122.1519';
$marker['infowindow_content'] = 'Welcome Googel Map';
$marker['icon'] = 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=A|9999FF|000000';
$this->googlemaps->add_marker($marker);

// Second Marker
$marker = array();
$marker['position'] = '37.409, -122.1319';
$marker['draggable'] = TRUE;
$marker['animation'] = 'DROP';
$this->googlemaps->add_marker($marker);

// third Marker
$marker = array();
$marker['position'] = '37.449, -122.1419';
$marker['onclick'] = 'alert("You just clicked on Maker!!")';
$this->googlemaps->add_marker($marker);

// Add Dyanamic Place name In Infowindow content
if(!empty($data['tunnels'])){
    foreach ($data['tunnels'] as $value) {
        $marker = array();
        $marker['position'] = $value->name.",".$value->city_name.",".$value->state_name.",".$value->country_name;
        $marker['infowindow_content'] = $value->name.",".$value->city_name.",".$value->state_name.",".$value->country_name;
        $marker['icon'] = 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=A|9999FF|000000';
        $this->googlemaps->add_marker($marker);
    }
}

$data['map'] = $this->googlemaps->create_map();
```

I hope this will helps you. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks it's nice but i want to add marker dynamically. For Ex. (I just want to show the name of places through marker ,stored in database)

Comment: please post your table structure to get name of places with lat & long.