# How i show multiple location in google map (Codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-maps

How i show multiple location in google map in Codeigniter. I have one array including latitude and longitude. I want to show all the location in map.

This is my `$query` array passed from controller to view page,

```
Array ( 
        [0] => stdClass Object ([lat] => 37.45360256419911 [lng] => -122.16470718383789) 
        [1] => stdClass Object ([lat] => 37.45455646705577 [lng] => -122.1653938293457) 
        [2] => stdClass Object ([lat] => 37.451543303913226 [lng] => -122.16745376586914) 
      )
```

i want to show all this 3 location in my map,now it's only marking 1 location.

```
<script>
    var map;
    var marker;
    var infowindow;
    var messagewindow;

    function initMap() {

    <?php
        foreach($query as $row){
            $lat=$row->lat;
            $lng=$row->lng;
    ?>

        var location = {lat: <?php echo $lat; ?>, lng: <?php echo $lng; ?>};
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: location,
            zoom: 13
        });

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: location,
            map: map,
        });


        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: document.getElementById('form')
        });

        messagewindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: document.getElementById('message')
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: event.latLng,
            map: map
        });


        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });
    });

<?php
    }
?>
    }
```

Comment: You can used this solution for your problem `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46093485/how-to-add-multiple-markers-in-google-map/46093758#46093758`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add Multiple-Markers in google map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46093485/how-to-add-multiple-markers-in-google-map)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.  The posted code only has one location (`var location`).

Comment: @geocodezip In my $query array more than one row that i shown above. I want to show all location in my map.for that i used foreach loop. var lacation that i put inside foreach loop.In my code iam trying to do loop will fetch all values in the array and mark each location. but it's only marking one row only

Comment: Second request. Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue (preferably a StackOverflow code snippet).  We can't tell what your PHP is doing, we don't have your database.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This code can display multi different markers. Hope this help you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Custom Markers</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>

        /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
        * element that contains the map. */
        #map {
            height: 100%;
        }

        /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
        var map;
        function initMap() {
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {             
                zoom: 16,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.91722, 151.23064),
                mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
            });

            var iconBase = 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/';
            var icons = {
                library: {
                    icon: iconBase + 'library_maps.png'
                },
                info: {
                    icon: iconBase + 'info-i_maps.png'
                }
            };

            var features = [

                // do looping here and replace LatLng value using foreach PHP.

                {
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.91721, 151.22630),
                    type: 'info'
                }, {
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.91539, 151.22820),
                    type: 'library'
                }, 

            ];

            // Create markers.
            features.forEach(function(feature) {
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: feature.position,
                    icon: icons[feature.type].icon,
                    map: map
                });
            });
        }
    </script>
    <script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

source : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/custom-markers

Comment: @Muhammad Rauuf Thank you so much ..i got it.

Answer (score 1):

```
It works fine for me...    
In controller : 

        function latLanLocation()
            {
               if($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
               {
                    $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
                    $data['title'] = 'Create client';

                    $ibo = $this->session->userdata['logged_in']['ibo'];

                    $latLanQuery = $this->db->query('select name,latitude,longitude from distributor_clients where sponsor='.$ibo.' AND status="A" AND latitude !=0 AND longitude !=0');

                    $userData = $latLanQuery->result_array();

                    $locations='[';
                    foreach ($userData as $key => $row) {
                        $name = $row['name'];
                        $longitude = $row['longitude'];                              
                        $latitude = $row['latitude'];

                        $locations .= '["'.$name.'","'.$latitude.'","'.$longitude.'"],';
                    }
                    $locations .= ']';

                    $data['markers'] =  $locations;

                    $this->load->view('location', $data);
               }
               else
               {
                 redirect('login', 'refresh');
               }
            }

    //In View folder create location.php
    // Html code for Google Map Javascript API
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
            <head>
                <style>
                    #mapCanvas {
                    height: 400px;
                    width: 100%;
                    }
                </style>
            </head>
            <body>
                <div id="mapCanvas"></div>
                <script>
                    function initMap() {
                        var map;
                        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
                        var mapOptions = {
                            mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
                        };

                        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapCanvas"), mapOptions);
                        map.setTilt(50);

                        var markers = <?php echo $markers; ?>

                        // Add multiple markers to map
                        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker, i;

                        // Place each marker on the map  
                        for( i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {
                            var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]);
                            bounds.extend(position);
                            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                position: position,
                                map: map,
                                title: markers[i][0]
                            });                                           


                            // Center the map to fit all markers on the screen
                            map.fitBounds(bounds);
                        }

                        // Set zoom level
                        var boundsListener = google.maps.event.addListener((map), 'bounds_changed', function(event) {
                            this.setZoom(14);
                            google.maps.event.removeListener(boundsListener);
                        });

                    }
                    // Load initialize function
                    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
                </script>
                <script async defer
                    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&callback=initMap"></script>
            </body>
        </html>
```

The final output:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but you could try like this. Put the php code before and generate an array of lat,lng coordinates which you convert to json for use by the `initmap` function. Iterate through the object members and add a new marker.

```
<?php
    $data=array();

    foreach($query as $row){
        $lat=$row->lat;
        $lng=$row->lng;
        $data[]=array('lat'=>$lat,'lng'=>$lng);
    }
    $json=json_encode( $data );
?>

<script>

    var map;
    var marker;
    var infowindow;
    var messagewindow;

    <?php
        echo "
        var json={$json};
        var lat={$lat}; 
        var lng={$lng};
        "
    ?>

    function initMap() {

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: location,
            zoom: 13
        });

        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: document.getElementById('form')
        });

        messagewindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: document.getElementById('message')
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener( map, 'click', function(event) {
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: event.latLng,
                map: map
            });
        });         


        for( var n in json ){
            var obj=json[ n ];
            lat=obj.lat;
            lng=obj.lng;
            var location = { lat:lat, lng:lng };

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: location,
                map: map,
            }); 

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            });             
        }
    }
</script>
```

---

Using the key you provided in the comment I get an error about an invalid key and the map refuses to load at all. Using a different key however worked fine with a couple of alterations.

My db connection is `mysqli` and the query and processing of recordset may or may not be the same method you chose. You need to edit this according to your needs as those details were ommited from the question.

```
<?php
    /* emulated db connection */
    include __DIR__. '/db.php';

    /* get markers from a table */
    $sql='select `name`,`lat`,`lng` from markers limit 20';
    $result=$db->query( $sql );

?>
<!--

    Original question:
    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48437784/how-i-show-multiple-location-in-google-map-codeigniter/48438084?noredirect=1#comment83871602_48438084

-->
<?php

    /* generate data array & convert to json */
    $data=array();
    /*
    foreach( $query as $row ){

    }
    */
    while( $row=$result->fetch_object() ){
        $lat=$row->lat;
        $lng=$row->lng;
        $name=$row->name;
        $data[]=array('name'=>$name,'lat'=>$lat,'lng'=>$lng);       
    }

    $json=json_encode( $data );
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Google maps - display markers</title>
        <script>

            var map;
            var marker;
            var infowindow;
            var messagewindow;



            <?php
                echo "
                var json={$json};
                var lat={$lat}; 
                var lng={$lng};
                "
            ?>

            function initMap() {
                var location=new google.maps.LatLng( lat,lng );
                map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById('map'), {
                    center: location,
                    zoom: 13
                });

                infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: document.getElementById('form')
                });

                messagewindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: document.getElementById('message')
                });

                google.maps.event.addListener( map, 'click', function(event) {
                    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: event.latLng,
                        map: map
                    });
                });         


                for( var n in json ){

                    var obj=json[ n ];
                    lat=obj.lat;
                    lng=obj.lng;
                    name=obj.name;

                    var location = new google.maps.LatLng( lat, lng );

                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: location,
                        title:name,
                        map: map,
                    }); 

                    google.maps.event.addListener( marker, 'click', function() {
                        var content=infowindow.getContent();                            
                        content.querySelector('input[name="lat"]').value=e.latLng.lat();                            
                        content.querySelector('input[name="lng"]').value=e.latLng.lng();                            
                        content.querySelector('input[name="name"]').value=this.title;

                        infowindow.open( map, this );
                    }.bind( marker )); /* bind to THIS marker */

                }
            }
        </script>
        <script async defer src='//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<API KEY>&callback=initMap'></script>
        <style>
            #map{
                width:800px;
                height:600px;
                float:none;
                margin:auto;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='map'></div>
        <form id='form'>
            <input type='text' name='lat' />
            <input type='text' name='lng' />
            <input type='submit' />
        </form>
        <div id='message'>unknown content</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: When i putting like this, not showing any marker. i got error in network tab in inspect                                                                          js?key=AIzaSyDz2oQPQR0EU45S6mBl7jry4e_PdmYM&callback=initMap:41 InvalidValueError: setPosition: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a number

Comment: you do not share your api key

Comment: I agree and I haven't but these are publicly accessible anyway so in this case no harm done as the api key the @OP gave is invalid anyway

Comment: @betofarina i know that, i already made some change in my api key.

Comment: @RamRaider Sorry i forgot to told you. It's working api i made some change because you know the reason, sorry.