# googlemaps codeigniter does not show in the view

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-maps-api-3

I have a problem with showing the maps on my codeigniter site. I am using googlemaps.php library, and my controller and view look like this:

Controller:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Maps extends My_Controller {

public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('Maps');

}

public function maps(){
    $this->load->library('googlemaps');
    $mapmarkers = $this->Maps->find(); //From here get lan. lat. 

    foreach($mapmarkers as $m){
        $marker = array();
        $marker['position'] = $m['location'];
        $content = "My Information";
        $marker['infowindow_content'] = $content ;
        $this->googlemaps->add_marker($marker);
    }

    $data['map'] = $this->googlemaps->create_map();
    //var_dump($data);
    $this->load_theme('maps', $data);
}
}
```

View:

```
<div class="map-content content-area container-fluid">
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $map['js']; ?>
        <?php echo $map['html']; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

The result is a blank page, but when I dump the variable `map`, it shows the correct data. 
I do not have any errors in the console either.

var_dump log:

```
array(1) { ["map"]=> array(3) { ["js"]=> string(1439) " " ["html"]=> string(61) "
 " ["markers"]=> array(1) { ["marker_0"]=> array(2) { ["latitude"]=> 
 string(17) "48.28866326125372" ["longitude"]=> string(17) 
 "16.37960056416341" } } } }
```

Can someone tell me what's wrong with my code, or how I can fix it

Comment: You need to initialize the map with some basic configurations `$this->googlemaps->initialize($config);`. Hope this helps!!

Comment: Please visit this link for your problem : [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46093485/how-to-add-multiple-markers-in-google-map/46093758#46093758). Hope it will helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

You are not `initialize` the library, update your function like following

```
public function maps(){
    $this->load->library('googlemaps');
    $this->googlemaps->initialize();

    $mapmarkers = $this->Maps->find(); //From here get lan. lat. 
    foreach($mapmarkers as $m){
        $marker = array();
        $marker['position'] = $m['location'];
        $marker['infowindow_content'] = 'My Information';
        $this->googlemaps->add_marker($marker);
    }

    $data['map'] = $this->googlemaps->create_map();
    //var_dump($data);
    $this->load_theme('maps', $data);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<head>
<?=$map['js'];?>
</head>

<body>
<?=$map['html'];?>
</body>
```

Comment: Same problem... nothing changed

Comment: what is in `load_theme` function .?/

Comment: path to template

Comment: inside the template call print_r($map)l check, if is data set to the variable or not